# What's under 0x400000 in virtual memory?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-memory, real-mode, protected-mode

When learning Linux Operating Systems, I know the following things:

1. Real mode will use addresss under 0x10000
2. Protected mode use 4G for 32bit, and the user space can use 2/3 G
3. The virtual memory for a program will start from 0x40000 to higher

So, what's under 0x400000, is it reserved?

Comment: ...mmmh, perhaps reserved for the kernel?

Comment: Real and Virtual 86 Mode actually uses *offsets* below 10000h (just like 16-bit Protected Mode). Combined with the real address mode segmentation scheme this allows access to the space of the first 10_0000h bytes (1 MiB). Additionally, the carry from high segments allows accessing an additional FFF0h bytes (64 KiB - 16 Byte), which is called the HMA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Maxim says, it's simply unmapped.  The pages in that region are marked as "not present" in the CPU's page tables, so that accessing them causes a page fault; and the kernel knows they are not backed by any physical memory, file, or swap space, so that such a page fault will be handled by delivering a segmentation fault signal (SIGSEGV) to the process, normally killing it.

It is desirable for at least the lowest page of a program's virtual address space to be unmapped, so that accesses to address 0 (null pointer dereference) will cause a segmentation fault instead of allowing a buggy program to continue running.  Leaving a larger region unmapped is also nice so that, for instance, if the program tries to access `p[i]` where `p` is a null pointer and `i` is somewhat greater than 4096, the program will again get a segfault.  In 32-bit mode, the value `0x400000` is convenient because this is 4 MB and corresponds to one entry in the page directory.  See https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging for an introduction to x86 paging.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I find something interesting: Windows will use the low address which is unmapped in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

> So, what's under 0x400000, is it reserved?

That's virtual address space that doesn't have any physical memory mapped. See [page table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) for more details.

You can view the virtual address space mappings of a process with:

```
cat /proc/<pid>/maps
```

Base address of `0x400000` is somewhat arbitrary, and address space randomisation (enabled by default) loads executables at different addresses at each run. You can observe the effect of address space randomisation by running `cat /proc/self/maps` twice and observing that `cat` executable is loaded at different virtual address on each run (provided `cat` is an executable and not a shell built-in).

The minimum virtual address is controlled by `vm.mmap_min_addr` `sysctl` variable. On Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS its default value is `65536` (`0x10000` in hex).